# "Global" variable scope in PHP

Tags: php, scope, global-variables

I have a section of code like the following:

---- file.php ----

```
require_once("mylib.php");

function($a,$b)
{
    $r = $_GLOBALS['someGlobal'];
    echo $r;
}
```

---

---- mylib.php ----

```
$_GLOBALS['someGlobal'] = "Random String";
```

---

This is a bit trivialized, but is the exact problem I have an I haven't found some related stuff, but nothing that answers my question directly.

When I call `function($a,$b)` nothing is echo'd, that is - `$r` is "empty" as if nothing was ever assigned to `$_GLOBALS['someGlobal']`;

In addition, I have tried with the following:

```
global $someGlobal;
$someGlobal = "Random String";
```

Same thing, no effect.
Also, in `file.php` if I try with `global`, or with just `$someGlobal` it still does not work.

As far as I know, from the documentation on php.net using global `$someGlobal` in mylib.php (and having that inserted in the top level of file.php) that it would not actually do much since it's already at the "top-level" of the scope hierarchy as far as I can tell. However, I thought registering it as a global might allow it to be accessed from inside the function, but this is clearly not the case.

Can anybody explain why, and explain how to get around this?

Edit: I should not that in file.php if I use `$_GLOBALS['someGlobal'];` the value is recovered fine if it's not in a function.

Comment: Wow... epic reading fail on my part.

Thanks folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong variable name.  It's `$GLOBALS` not `$_GLOBALS`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php), there is no `_` in the `$GLOBALS` variable:

This works fine for me:

```
$GLOBALS['glob'] = "string";

function foob() {
  echo $GLOBALS['glob'];
}

foob();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `$GLOBALS`, not `$_GLOBALS`!